# UILabel don't display

Tags: ios, swift

I have UILabel in my storyboard wanna show a very long string.But it did not show up.

When I insert a "hello world ",it shows up.however, insert a long string what i want to show , it did not work.

```
import UIKit

class VersionInformationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var version: UILabel!
    static func instantiateViewController() -> VersionInformationViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "VersionInformation", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "versionInformation") as! VersionInformationViewController
        return vc
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        fetchLibraryLicense()

    }

    // MARK: - private
    private func fetchLibraryLicense(){
        var VersionInformation:String = "";
        let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CarthageLicenseList", ofType: "plist")!);
        let array = dictionary?["PreferenceSpecifiers"] as! NSArray

        for dic in array {
            let dictionary = dic as! NSDictionary
            let title:String = (dictionary["Title"] as? String)!
            let footerText:String = (dictionary["FooterText"] as? String)!

            VersionInformation = VersionInformation + title + footerText
        }
        print(VersionInformation)
        version.text = "hello world" //it works
        version.text = VersionInformation // it did not work
    }

}
```

Comment: but you do not have a linefeed as first sign in Versioninformation and your label has just one line....? ;)

Comment: Are you set `linebreakmode` for the UILabel?

Comment: First try with `numberOfLines = 1` for multi line label. if text is displayed then set the number of line to zero and set line breaking mode `.byWordWrap`. and set the proper constraints. Also change label's content hugging priority if needed.

Comment: @Mahendra I've try with  `numberOfLines = 1`, and actually displayed the first line. However, when i set the breaking mode to  `byWordWrap` The reason is that  `VersionInformation`, is too long that over the height.But I don't know how to max the height cuz it is included in StackView that can't over 10000.